# Make wsp compatible for sp2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio, solution-package, solution-deployment, 2019

I will do a migration from SP2016 to SP2019.
My question is for WSP , what I need to change exactly to be compatible with SP19, and how to do it?

Using visual studio is there a config file to change.

Comment: Is it possible to deploy a wsp package built for SP2019 on SP2016? Is there any technical restriction to deploy it on the lower version of SP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing as far as I know.  SP2013, 2016 and 2019 all have the same compatibility level (15, in this case).  The only issue you’ll run into is if you’re accessing something in 2016 that doesn’t exist in 2019.

I’ve successfully deployed WSPs built for SP2013 (exact same file) on SP2019 and the functionality was running as expected.

Comment: thank you for your feedback

Comment: As always, testing needs to be done to make sure everything works